# How to enable the codefolding in jupyter notebook, using the R kernel

Tags: r, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions#installation) but somehow, I cannot enable the extension 'codefolding'. In the console, it says that I enabled it. If I, however, look within the notebook at the Configurable nbextensions, I cannot click on it. Instead of the square, there is an exclamation mark. Does anyone know how to change this?

If I ran the code {{n}} in markdown, I get the following error message:

> Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): :1:3: unerwartetes Symbol 1: a is ^ Traceback:

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation mark is used to indicate an nbextension which the configurator isn't *certain* has been declared to be compatible with the notebook version you're running (e.g. running notebook `5.0.1`, but nbextension only declares it's compatibility as `4.x`). The configurator should have a checkbox above its list of configurable nbextensions to allow/prevent configuring nbextensions which are "potentially incompatible" in this way. In most cases, this can be ignored as the nbextension *is* still compatible. Codefolding in particular, should have been updated to list as 5.x compatible, so it may be worth updating your nbextensions install.

Your second issue, with the `{{n}}` in a markdown cell causing problems, sounds like it's because you've enabled the "python-markdown" nbextension which attempts to evaluate the contents of tags like that in the (python) kernel, but you're using an r kernel...